# SQL Server 2005 - Index of updt_tmstmp field

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am investigating indexes and have read through many articles and would like some expert advice.  As a warning, index fields are fairly new to me and a bit confusing even after reading up on the subject!

To simplify, I have a table that has a guid (transaction id), event id and an updt_tmstmp (there are many other fields but unimportant to this question).

My PK is the transaction_id and event_id and the table is ordered by these keys.  Since the transaction_id is a guid, the updt_tmstmp field is very randomized.  As the table has grown to 6 million records the query has slowed.  My idea was to add an index on the updt_tmstmp field.  Our extracts search often on the table and look for the transaction_id's that have had updates in the past 24 hours.  The query is scanning the entire table to find the records that have updated.  Average time 1 minute

Details Current:
Table size:  6.2 million records
Index:  transaction_id + event_id (clustered)

Details Attempted:
Additional Index:  updt_tmstmp (non-unique, non-clustered)

When I did this update and ran the query it improved by about 10% and the explain plan indicates I am still table scanning an index.  I expected a little bit better performance than this.  My updt_tmstmp is not guaranteed to be unique (I blame the application programmer for doing this :) ).

The query I am using to access this is a standard start_time - end_time.  updt_tmstmp >= @start_time and updt_tmstmp < @end_time

Thanks in advance and have a great day!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Question: Given a clustered index on event_ID, and non_clustered indexes on transaction_id and updt_tmstmp, I would recommend the following:

-- drop the clustered index on event_id and the non-clustered index on updt_tmstmp.
-- Create the clustered index on updt_tmstmp.

Logic: The SQL Server query optimizer has always favored clustered indexes over non-clustered indexes.  The showplan for the query most likes shows a clustered index SCAN when using event_id as the clustered index.  By moving the clustered index to updt-tmstmp, the query showplan should show a range search for all transactions in the last 24 hours and should do it quickly because the cluster key is sorted and is physically adjacent on disk... perfect for a range scan of a cluster.

By doing this, you will have accomplished a few key design goals.

Defined the clustered index key with as few columns as possible, considering columns that have one that are very selective  or contain many distinct values

-- Also... the updt-tmpstmp field data will be accessed sequentially and rarely if at all updated.  Perfect for a clustered index. The updt-tmstmp field will be used frequently to sort the data retrieved from the table.

I suggest that you use the following before the query to assist you in understand query optimizing behavior.

set statistics io on
go
set statistics time on
go

Table 
 Name of the table.

Scan count 
 Number of index or table scans performed.

logical reads 
 Number of pages read from the data cache.

physical reads 
 Number of pages read from disk.

read-ahead reads 
 Number of pages placed into the cache for the query.

lob logical reads 
 Number of text, ntext, image, or large value type (varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max)) pages read from the data cache.

lob physical reads 
 Number of text, ntext, image or large value type pages read from disk.

lob read-ahead reads 
 Number of text, ntext, image or large value type pages placed into the cache for the query.

SQL Server parse and compile elapsed time and cpu

SQL Server Execution Time and cpu